# Changing margin on template CV source code without additional packages (not solved)

Tags: margins

I wish to change the margin for the right-hand side in the following code. How can this be done in order to widen the margin in the RHS only?

EDIT: I don't want to add any more packages as it messes with the rest of the formatting of this template - can someone help me edit this source code with the existing packages to change the RHS margin? Would really be appreciated!

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{John Smith}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}\vspace{0.5em} % Personal information heading

\NewEntry{}{\textit{Born in Canada,}}{20 November 1987} % Birthplace and date

\NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}} % Email address

\NewEntry{website}{\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{http://www.johnsmith.com}} % Personal website

\NewEntry{phone}{(H) +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +1 (000) 111 1112} % Phone number(s)

\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} % Goal heading, could be used for a quotation or short profile instead

\Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}\vspace{2em} % Goal text

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Work Experience}\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst, \textsc{Lehman Brothers}}

\Description{\MarginText{Lehman Brothers}Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping. \\ Reference: John \textsc{McDonald}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:john@lehman.com}{john@lehman.com}}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: with use of `geometry` package?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion - could you provide an example?

Comment: `\usepackage[left=<desired length>,right=<desired length>]{geometry}`. where `left` determine left margin and `right` right margin at `oneside` documents. at two side you replace them with `inner` and  `outer` respectively. for all options see package documentation (on page 3 is sketch of all options).

Comment: Hi, when I do that (via \usepackage[left=12em,right=3.5em]{geometry}) It changes the vertical margins as well in the following pages (increases them). Is there a way of changing the template code above to allow for wider RHS margin without using a different package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way is use of geometry package, but you can try

```
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{<lenght>}
```

where lenght is amount by which you like to change odd margin and

```
\addtotlength\textwidth{<lenght>}
```

where lenght is again amount by which you like to increase text width.

for details see [wikibook (page layout)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout).

Comment: I get an error when I add that to my code:
"! Undefined control sequence.
l.44 \addtotlength
                  \oddsidemargin{4em}"

Would you mind using the code I posted and editing it to show me how you'd do it?

Comment: sorry, i make type errors: `\addtotlength` (notice wrong `t` before `l`) should be `\addtolength`. now the answer is corrected and should work. unfortunately i can't test your *mwe* since i haven't packages used for styles in it.